# Soma no sql update

Tags: mysql

Estou rodando o seguinte sql no meu mysql:

```
UPDATE `cadastro` SET `pontos`= 'pontos + 1' WHERE id = 102;
```

Preciso que a cada vez que ele seja feito o Update na tabela *cadastro*  o campo *pontos* que é do tipo `int(11)` receba +1;

Quando rodo esse `sql` ele não me retorna erro, porém, o campo `pontos` continua sempre com o valor 1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você esta tentando somar uma string, tente da maneira abaixo:

```
UPDATE `cadastro` SET `pontos` = `pontos` + 1 WHERE id = 102;
```

Lembrando que para funcionar a coluna pontos deve ser de um tipo numérico. Exemplo: `int`, `double`, `float`, etc...

Comment: Perfeito amigo, obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Solução para um cenário **sem concorrência**:

```
UPDATE cadastro SET pontos = pontos + 1 WHERE id = 102;
```

Uma consideração muito importante quando se faz esse tipo de atualização é a concorrência de acessos de gravação na tabela `cadastro`.

Se dois cliente executarem o `UPDATE` acima simultaneamente, o dado contido no campo `pontos` corre o risco de não ficar como o esperado.

A Solução para um cenário **com concorrência** seria essa:

```
START TRANSACTION;

-- Recupera O valor para atualização
SELECT pontos FROM cadastro WHERE id = 102 FOR UPDATE;

-- Incrementa o contador
UPDATE cadastro SET pontos = pontos + 1 WHERE id = 102;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Da sua forma está dando o seguinte erro: `#1064 - Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a 'LIMIT 0, 25' na linha 1`